# How to work with hooks and Posts to posts plugin?

Tags: hooks, plugin-posts-to-posts

I am using Scribu's [Posts to posts](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Basic-usage) plugin to create connections between posts. For example I have custom post type `Lesson`, and to every lesson one (or more) `Teacher` can be connected. Connection is initialized with `p2p_init` hook (and this hook is added to WP with `wp_loaded` hook). So far all good.

Problem is I am used to process all background actions with `init` hook. For example webpage generates application form for every lesson, visitor can sign up, and I want to save his data and send him e-mail with application summary. Example code (not real):

```
function save_application_and_send_email() {
    if( isset($_POST['application']) ) {

        // ... process and save application / visitor data

        // ... generate e-mail with all information

        $connected = new WP_Query( array(
          'connected_type' => 'teachers_to_lessons',
          'connected_items' => $lesson_object
        ) );
        if( $connected->have_posts() ) { 
            // get teacher name etc.
        }

        // WRONG - $connected query is empty (no "teacher" posts)

        // send e-mail
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'save_application_and_send_email' );
```

Calling my function on `init` hook works, but "Posts to posts" connection is not alive yet and no teacher post is returned. When I hook my function to `wp_loaded` hook, all works as usual AND connected teachers are found. Profit!

**My question:** **What is correct hook to handling $_POST and $_GET data?** I always thought it's [`init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init), as it is written in its documentation. But if I want to work with Posts to posts plugin, I have to use [`wp_loaded`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_loaded) now. What does it generally mean for my code? Does it change something important?

As I am bothering with this issue, I am maybe realizing that hooking background actions and data processing to `wp_loaded` hook is *better* than to `init`. Is it true?

Comment: If you need to access post data, the safest hook to use is [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect). By the time this hook fires, all postdata is known, but the templates are not yet set

Comment: No, I don't need post data (mostly). And I need hook available in admin request, too.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the plugin (which I have never used) needs postdata to establish relationships between posts, so that is why I'm thinking about the `template_redirect` hook. As for admin area, I'm not quite sure though

Comment: Ah, now I understand :) Actually, the plugin uses [two new DB tables](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Data-organization), so I think it doesn't need traditional post data. Moreover, I am using it in custom WP_Query loops. Well, `wp_loaded` looks promising.